# How are image saved in arrays ,in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

Images are stored as multidimensional arrays in opencv . But how do these arrays look like ?
(I am providing answer ,so that this topic is closed forever :D)

Answer (score 4):

2d images (which are normally images we work most of time) are simply array of array . Let me create a grayscale image to make you understand .

```
       myArray = [[236, 189, 0],[236, 80, 189],
       [236, 0, 189],
       [236, 189, 0]]
```

myArray is list of list(or array of array) which represents image of width 3 and height 4 . ie. in this nested array , each list represents each row of image .
here is a code to show what myarray looks like diagrammatically :

```
myArray = [[255, 0, 189],
       [236, 80, 200],
       [255, 0, 200],
       [200, 100, 255]]
import numpy
imgArray = numpy.array(myArray) #because normal array is not recognized , dont know why , if you know please comment 




import cv2
cv2.imwrite("test.png",imgArray)
```

OUTPUT image is :

[image: image constructed form array]